# How to deploy React application to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, heroku-ci

I have built a single-page weather app with React and Node.js but can't seem to get it to deploy to Heroku. So far, I have:

1. Created a new app on Heroku called weather-app-react-node
2. Logged into Heroku on the CLI
3. Run the command 'heroku git:remote -a weather-app-react-node' in my terminal
4. Added a Procfile with 'web: npm start' in it
5. Ran 'git add .', 'git commit -m "Pushed to heroku"',  'git push heroku master'

My terminal tells me it is deployed and waiting but when I click on the link, I get this error message:

```
SecurityError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.
```

I've tried to google it but can't seem to find anything relevant to my situation. Anyone know how to fix it?

heroku-site: https://weather-app-react-node.herokuapp.com/
github: https://github.com/caseycling/weather-app

Answer (score 9):

To deploy the React app to Heroku, I performed the following steps...

**1.** In your terminal, enter `npm -v` and `node -v` to get your npm and node version. In my case, my npm version is `6.14.1` & my node version is `12.13.0`.

**2.** In `package.json`, add `"main": "server.js",` and `"engines": { "npm": "6.14.1", "node": "12.13.0" },` under the `"private"` property. In your `scripts` property, add    `"heroku-postbuild": "npm install"` and set `"start"` to `"node server.js"`.

[image]

**3.** In the root directory, create a `Procfile` with one line of text: `web: node server.js`.

**4.** In the root directory, create the `server.js` file with the below code..

```js
const express = require("express");
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
// const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));

// This route serves the React app
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "build", "index.html")));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`));
```

**5.** Enter `npm run build` in the terminal to produce the `build` directory. Next, remove (or comment out) `/build` from `.gitignore` file (in root directory).

**6.** Test if `server.js` works by entering `node server.js` (or `nodemon server.js`) in the terminal. If it works, `server.js` should serve the React app.

**7.** Commit everything from step 1-6 to GitHub and Heroku repository. To commit to Heroku repository, in your terminal, enter `heroku git:remote -a weather-app-react-node` and afterward, enter `git push heroku master`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try logging in to heroku directly and deploy your github repository's desired branch from there directly.

Comment: It might be related to your api call to openweathermap. Can you double check if you have the right format for the request URL and a valid auth key?

Comment: So i figured out that one of my issues was I didn't have a server built. I added a server.js file and built a server with express but now it is giving me the basic Application Error message

Comment: Application Error message is normally caused by your application code base. I suggest going through [this link](https://daveceddia.com/deploy-react-express-app-heroku/).

Comment: After going through your github repository it seems like you dont need an express server. Heroku offers deployment of react projects with made `create-react-app` with zero configurations. Check out [this link](https://dev.to/smithmanny/deploy-your-react-app-to-heroku-2b6f)

Answer (score 0):

I used create-react-app-buildpack

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
git init
heroku create -b https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git
or
heroku create -b mars/create-react-app
git add .
git commit -m "I am the newborn app"
git push heroku master
heroku open
```

Note: In my case, buildpack config from CLI did not work, I still had nodejs-build pack, so I manually changed the build pack to `mars/create-react-app` in the Heroku project dashboard

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to push React apps to Heroku with a node js backend is to use the Heroku Post Build Script, The post build will take care of all the work under the hood

**Follow the steps below**

Add This below snippet to your package.json under the scripts

```js
    scripts{
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix reactFolderName && npm run build --prefix reactFolderName"
}
```

And add this snippet to your index.js file

```js
    app = express()
    app.use(express.static('reactFolderName/build'));
    app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'reactFolderName', 'build', 'index.html')));
```

Answer (score 0):

After I set up the all the things above mentioned I'm facing this issue.

When I'm using the URL like `http://localhost:8080/` & `http://localhost:8080/button`

```
Cannot GET /button
```

In Console

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status 
of 404 (Not Found)
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content 
for chrome- 
extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/browser- 
polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```